# Default Firefox browser not playing some content

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, video, 20.04, codecs

I can't play videos like the ones on most twitter posts, for example, https://twitter.com/doglab/status/1255593258916499458?s=20. However, Chrome plays them.

Also is there any recommended set of installs that power users can do a day or two after getting Ubuntu 20.04 to get the most used video codecs and other tools?

solved with

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt upgrade -y

sudo apt install ffmpeg
```

and ubuntu-restricted-extra via the checkbox in "Software and Updates" panel -> https://postimg.cc/yWx4qS90

[image: Software and Updates panel with checkboxes checked]

Comment: Is `ubuntu-restricted-extras` installed? The video plays for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and after running the following command :

`sudo apt install ffmpeg`

It's a big install just for playing videos in firefox, but at least it works, and having ffmpeg on your system might always be useful.

Comment: also  `sudo apt update` and 

`sudo apt upgrade -y` helped